# Stopping Devstack from running every time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, openstack

I installed [DevStack](http://devstack.org) on my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop. But now, every time I start my laptop, the Apache HTTP servers and MySQL daemon are running at startup. Is there anyway to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those applications are considered services so you're going to want to do 2 things. First stop them now, you can use the `service` command to stop them. Second you're going to want to disable them permanently between reboots.

You can use this command to see all the services available and their state.

```
% service --status-all
 [ - ]  NetworkManager.dpkg-backup
 [ ? ]  acpi-support
 [ ? ]  acpid
 [ ? ]  alsa-restore
 [ ? ]  alsa-store
 [ ? ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ ? ]  apmd
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ - ]  bootlogd
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 ...
```

Once you've identified which services are running you can use this command to stop them.

```
% service apache2 stop
% service mysqld stop
...
```

Finally to permanently disable these services use one of the forms of the ommand.

- echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override
- update-rc.d apache2 disable